# Logrotate: glob finding old rotated logs failed

Tags: rsyslog, logrotate

I am having problems with logrotate. The configuration is the following

```
/var/log/cron
/var/log/maillog
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
/var/log/spooler
/var/log/unused.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/daemon.log
{
    #Modified by CGSL!
    compress
    dateext
    maxage 90
    rotate 100
    missingok
    notifempty
    size +4096k
    create 640 root root
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

I am interested in rotating the /var/log/daemon.log, the output of executing

```
logrotate -fv /etc/logrotate.d/syslog
```

is

```
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/syslog
reading config info for /var/log/cron
/var/log/maillog
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
/var/log/spooler
/var/log/unused.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/daemon.log


Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/cron
/var/log/maillog
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
/var/log/spooler
/var/log/unused.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/daemon.log
 forced from command line (100 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/cron
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/maillog
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/messages
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/secure
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/spooler
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/unused.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/kern.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/daemon.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/cron, log->rotateCount is 100
dateext suffix '-20190411'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
rotating log /var/log/maillog, log->rotateCount is 100
dateext suffix '-20190411'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
rotating log /var/log/messages, log->rotateCount is 100
dateext suffix '-20190411'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
destination /var/log/messages-20190411.gz already exists, skipping rotation
rotating log /var/log/secure, log->rotateCount is 100
dateext suffix '-20190411'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
rotating log /var/log/unused.log, log->rotateCount is 100
dateext suffix '-20190411'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
rotating log /var/log/kern.log, log->rotateCount is 100
dateext suffix '-20190411'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding old rotated logs failed
rotating log /var/log/daemon.log, log->rotateCount is 100
dateext suffix '-20190411'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding old rotated logs failed
set default create context
```

What does this error mean?

```
glob finding old rotated logs failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved using

```
logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/syslog
```

without "v" option.

Comment: How is hiding the verbose option the solution ?